# Why two arrays of objects are not equal in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I can't understand why it's always shows NOT equal in code :

```
 if(JSON.stringify(data.content.items) != JSON.stringify(updatedItems)) {
            console.log('update');

            updatedItems = data.content.items;  // updatedItems -global variable
        }
```

I receive array of objects and check every second if it's equal or not.

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: Have you tried using [angular.equals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular.fromJson(json)` instead. It will strip the `$$hashKey`, that's making it not equal